# How do I use Javascript to return the text of the paragraph clicked as a usable variable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, addeventlistener

I'm new to Javascript and self taught, my english is a little rough too, please bare with me. I've searched all over and tried everything I can.

I'm trying to make a table of content where clicking it brings up a form modal.. I want that when the form opens the innerHTML of the button clicked becomes a variable on it's own. It will be submitted alongside other form inputs..
I just want to extract the paragraph text and use it as a variable that can be recall or something like that.
I can't seem to get the topicHeading variable out of the for loop, I get undefined.

```js
var topicHeading;
var topicButtons = document.querySelectorAll('p[class^=topicName]');

for (var i = 0; i < topicButtons.length; i++) {
  topicButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var topicHeading = this.innerHTML;
    return topicHeading;
  });
};

console.log(topicHeading);
```

```html
<div class="wallet-buttons" id="walletsList">

  <div id="Topic1" class="button-section" onclick="opendetails()">
    <i class="active-icon"></i>
    <div class="btn-name">
      <p class="topicName">Topic 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-img">
      <img src="img/topicimg.svg" alt="Topic Image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Topic2" class="button-section" onclick="opendetails()">
    <i class="active-icon"></i>
    <div class="btn-name">
      <p class="topicName">Topic 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-img">
      <img src="img/topicimg.svg" alt="Topic Image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Topic3" class="button-section" onclick="opendetails()">
    <i class="active-icon"></i>
    <div class="btn-name">
      <p class="topicName">Topic 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-img">
      <img src="img/topicimg.svg" alt="Topic Image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Topic4" class="button-section" onclick="opendetails()">
    <i class="active-icon"></i>
    <div class="btn-name">
      <p class="topicName">Topic 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-img">
      <img src="img/topicimg.svg" alt="Topic Image">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `var` declaration in the function. That's creating a local variable instead of assigning the global variable.

Comment: There's no point in `return topicHeading`. The return value of an event listener isn't used.

Comment: Regardless of any of this, `console.log()` won't show that the user has clicked on, since it's running immediately, not after the user clicks.

Comment: Please, is there a way I can get the paragraph text from the button clicked into a variable?.. 
I feel like I’m in over my head with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting a variable, pass the value to the `opendetails()` function.

```js
var topicButtons = document.querySelectorAll('p.topicName');

for (var i = 0; i < topicButtons.length; i++) {
  topicButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var topicHeading = this.innerHTML;
    opendetails(topicHeading);
  });
};

document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", function() {
  opendetails(topicHeading);
})

function opendetails(details) {
  console.log(details);
}
```

```html
<div class="wallet-buttons" id="walletsList">

  <div id="Topic1" class="button-section">
    <i class="active-icon"></i>
    <div class="btn-name">
      <p class="topicName">Topic 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-img">
      <img src="img/topicimg.svg" alt="Topic Image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Topic2" class="button-section">
    <i class="active-icon"></i>
    <div class="btn-name">
      <p class="topicName">Topic 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-img">
      <img src="img/topicimg.svg" alt="Topic Image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Topic3" class="button-section">
    <i class="active-icon"></i>
    <div class="btn-name">
      <p class="topicName">Topic 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-img">
      <img src="img/topicimg.svg" alt="Topic Image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Topic4" class="button-section">
    <i class="active-icon"></i>
    <div class="btn-name">
      <p class="topicName">Topic 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-img">
      <img src="img/topicimg.svg" alt="Topic Image">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<p>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. 
I tried the same with getting the topic image, but it won't log the output until I click twice the element twice... Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/testerofrester/gmk1pzq6/

Comment: `opendetails()` is running before the event listener that sets `topicImage()`. Don't mix `addEventListener()` with `onclick` attributes.

Comment: Please, is it possible to make the event listener run on click and set the variable? I'm trying to get the topic title and image

Comment: Why don't you just call `opendetails()` from the event listener, and pass the variable to it as an argument?

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I that? So far, I only understand JS by simple algorithms... I want to do something like when `<div>`  with `class="button-section"` is click, it should copy the innerHTML in its child element with the `btn-img` class and set it as a variable..

Comment: I've update the answer to show how to call `opendetails()` from the event listener instead of setting a global variable.